# Install MySQL 5.1 Using Clang

Tags: mysql, c, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to downgrade my current version of MySQL on OSX (Lion) to version 5.1 for work reasons. I uninstalled mysql using `brew uninstall mysql`. When I try to install brew's version package for MySQL 5.1, using `brew install mysql51`, I get the following error:

```
C++ standard library: libstdc++ (from clang)

This is incompatible with the standard library being used
to build mysql51: libstdc++ (from gcc-4.6)
```

I tried running `brew install mysql51 --with-clang` and `brew install mysql51 --use-clang`, which both yielded the same error. How can I get brew to use the clang  compiler to install MySQL?